# can't find file that was supposedly successfully downloaded with AFDownloadRequestOperation

Tags: ios, download

I download a file:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:episode.enclosure_url]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *fileExtension = [episode.enclosure_url pathExtension];
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[episode.enclosure_urlAlphanumericOnly stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@", fileExtension]]];

AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:path shouldResume:YES];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                    // COMPLETION BLOCK
                    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);

                    downloadInfo.filePath = path;
                    downloadInfo.isComplete = @YES;

                    // save context
                    NSError *error;
                    BOOL success = [self.workerContext save:&error];
                    if (!success || error) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                    }
…
```

And the successful-completion block triggers, logging:

```
Successfully downloaded file to /Users/myName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1-64/Applications/D629F52C-E299-42C7-BF7E-DF8D096529C7/Documents/httppodcastdownloadnprorganonnprpodcastspodcast13308789280npr308789280mp3.mp3
```

Then I check for the file's existence:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[localUrl path]]) {
    …
```

The file cannot be found. I also don't see any new file in Finder.

Why might it be that `AFDownloadRequestOperation` indicates a successful download, but the file seems not to exist? Or what's a good alternative means of downloading with resume capability? Thanks